# after unziping not able to write the file from source to destination in python

Tags: python

I am using the following code to unzip. It's able to read and print the source. However it is not writing to the destination

```
my_dir = r"D:\Download"
my_zip = r"D:\Download\my_file.zip"
with zipfile.ZipFile(my_zip) as zip_file:
    for member in zip_file.namelist():
        filename = os.path.basename(member)
        # skip directories
        if not filename:
            continue
        #copy file (taken from zipfile's extract)
        source = zip_file.open(member)
        target = file(os.path.join(my_dir, filename), "wb")
        with source, target:
            shutil.copyfileobj(source, target)
```

Further information that the author left in the comment:

> Yes, I type the script name in a console. Though it is able to read the file, its not able to write it to the destination. It throws an error "str object not callable" – Brad 4 hours ago
>
> The problem is with this line: target = file(os.path.join(my_dir, filename), "wb") TypeError: 'str' object is not callable – Brad 4 hours ago

Comment: Might be OS dependent: I've just tested your script on a GNU/Linux distro and it works as expected.

Comment: Also, how do you invoke the script? I mean, just double click the file icon or typing something like `python foo.py` in a console? `shutil.copyfileobj` shall have raised some error when it fails, e.g. `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: foo/bar`

Comment: Yes, I type the script name in a console.
Though it is able to read the file, its not able to write it to the destination.
It throws an error "str object not callable"

Comment: The problem is with this line:
    target = file(os.path.join(my_dir, filename), "wb")
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: I've edited your original question to add the very useful information in your comments.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is with this line: target = file(os.path.join(my_dir, filename), "wb") TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

It's highly suspected that you have assigned a string to the name `file` previously, e.g. `file = 'foo.py'`. Please check your code.

Also, instead of `file(os.path.join(my_dir, filename), "wb")`, you could also use `open(os.path.join(my_dir, filename), "wb")`

The next time please include all related information (e.g. details of the error) in the question body.